# kubelet doesn't seem to be using correct user when registering node

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

When kubelet tries to start on my Kubernetes worker nodes, I'm getting messages like this in the system log:

```
May 25 19:43:57 ip-10-240-0-223 kubelet[4882]: I0525 19:43:57.627389    4882 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node worker-1
May 25 19:43:57 ip-10-240-0-223 kubelet[4882]: E0525 19:43:57.628967    4882 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "worker-1" with API server: nodes is forbidden: User "system:node:" cannot create nodes at the cluster scope: unknown node for user "system:node:"
May 25 19:43:58 ip-10-240-0-223 kubelet[4882]: E0525 19:43:58.256557    4882 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:node:" cannot list services at the cluster scope: unknown node for user "system:node:"
May 25 19:43:58 ip-10-240-0-223 kubelet[4882]: E0525 19:43:58.257381    4882 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:node:" cannot list pods at the cluster scope: unknown node for user "system:node:"
```

If I'm reading these correctly, the problem is that the node is using the username `system:node:` when connecting to the API server rather than `system:node:worker-1`.   But as far as I can tell, it should be using a worker-specific one.   Here's my `kubeconfig` (with private stuff elided):

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: [elided]
    server: https://[elided]:6443
  name: kubernetes-the-hard-way
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes-the-hard-way
    user: system:node:worker-1
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: system:node:worker-1
  user:
    client-certificate-data:  [elided]
    client-key-data:  [elided]
```

I was under the impression that the `user`s specified there were the ones used when contacting the API, but clearly I'm wrong.   Is there somewhere else I've missed out a reference to `worker-1`?

I'm following the [Kubernetes the Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) tutorial, but adjusting it for AWS as I go, so this problem is almost certainly a mistake I made when adjusting the config files.  If there are any other config files that I should provide to make this easier/possible to debug, please do let me know.

Comment: What k8s version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current "Kubernetes-The-Hard-Way" is using [Node Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/node/) so
ensure your kubelet x509 certificates contains

```
Subject: CN=system:node:worker-1, O=system:nodes
```

Also double check your API server have these options

```
--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
--enable-admission-plugins=...,NodeRestriction,...
```

otherwise the node won't be able to auto-register in the API.

You can check your x509 certificate with

```
openssl x509 -in /var/lib/kubelet/${HOSTNAME}.pem -text
```

Comment: Thanks!   That was exactly it.   I regenerated the certs with the correct CN, and also had to regenerate the kubeconfig files, as they have the certificates embedded.   Once those files were uploaded, and kubelet was restarted, it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The server determines the user from the CN of the certificate. Check the script that generated the certificate, it likely had an unset var when it created the CN in the form `CN=system:node:$NODE`

Comment: Thanks!   That was exactly it.   I regenerated the certs with the correct CN, and also had to regenerate the kubeconfig files, as they have the certificates embedded.   Once those files were uploaded, and kubelet was restarted, it all worked fine.